# Combining removeClass() and data() to remember which elements had the class and restore it

Tags: javascript, jquery, restore, removeclass

So I previously asked similar question but few hours later when I tried to use it I couldn't exactly figure out how to use it. I was told the following:

```
$(element).removeClass('active');
$(element).data('removed-class', 'active');
```

Further it can be fetched using

```
var removeClass = $(element).data('removed-class');
```

So what exactly would be the most "clean" way to get it to function?

So basically, if I have 7 `<li>` rows, and randomly 3 of the `<li>` have the class "active".

Now, if I execute an function that performs to remove all the "active" classes from the `<li>` with `$("li").removeClass("active")` for example, how can I now restore the same "active" `<li>` classes that had the class removed?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot, and see if it fits the bill.

```
var $listItems = $('li','#wrapper');

function clsToData (elements, cls) {
    $(elements).each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.hasClass(cls)){
            $this.removeClass(cls).data('removed-class',cls);
        }
    });
}

function restoreRemovedClasses (elements) {
    $(elements).each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass($this.data('removed-class'));
    });
}

$('button','#buttons').on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    switch ($this.attr('id')){
        case "button1":
            clsToData($listItems,'active');
            break;
        case "button2":
            restoreRemovedClasses ($listItems);
            break;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rA5aF/

Comment: Cheers, that's exactly what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").addClass($("li").data('removed-class'));
```

Except you should probably target the appropriate elements, not every `li` element in the DOM.